# Overload caret operator for string evaluation in Python

Tags: python, operator-overloading, eval

The easiest way to bypass a current problem I have is to interpret the caret operator (^) as a power operator, which in Python is **. I need to evaluate strings of arithmetic with this new definition of ^, so I am using `eval()` to accomplish this. I know the dangers of Python's `eval()` but this code will *only ever* be used by myself.

To accomplish the operator overloading I have done:

```
class Pow(float):
    def __xor__(self, other):
        return self ** other

# Give a value for the variable and define using new Class Pow
A = Pow(2.4)

eval("A^3")
```

This works great, but for any operator placed before or after the power in the string, e.g.:

```
eval("1+A^3")
eval("A^3+A")
etc...
```

Results in:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for ^: 'float' and 'int'
```

Or the incorrect answer.

If all the power terms are placed in brackets, e.g.:

```
eval("1+(A^3)")
eval("(A^3)+A")
```

Then everything works great again as the correct Class syntax is now being satisfied. Replacing the ^ characters in the string with ** beforehand is not ideal so I was wondering if there is a way to 'more robustly' overload the caret operator for arithmetic evaluation as though it were a traditional power operator. If not, is there a better way to accomplish this task?

Comment: Look here: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#operator-precedence. It has to do with precedence. `+` is going to be evaluated before the bitwise operator `^`. That is why you are seeing it work with explicit parentheses.

Comment: You could use something like this maybe: eval("A^2+1".replace("^","**"))